# how to heat a wood kiln to 140 F safely

Tags: kiln-dried-wood

I am trying to heat a wood kiln safely to 140 degrees F.
Ideally there would be a commercial product available. All electrical heaters have a high temp cut off switch around 120F that protects the heater.
The only option I can think off is have the heater outside and duct the hot air inside, but that causes other issues with pressure and the unit not sealed.

Are there any electrical products rated at or above 140F that would be suitable.

Comment: Then list one then. I can't find any...

Comment: https://www.mcmaster.com/#strip-heaters/=1a5hv7j or https://www.mcmaster.com/#heaters/=1a5hqzz or https://www.mcmaster.com/#heaters/=1a5htku or https://www.mcmaster.com/#heaters/=1a5huhm or a hot water heater, a circulator pump, and a roll of PEX tubing.

Comment: Many DIY designs just use a dehumidifier and blower, so any heat is an indirect result of that.

Answer (score 1):

I built a DIY jar preheater for my candle business from an old cabinet about 5 feet long by about two feet deep and two feet wide and heat it with 3 - 250 watt heat lamps (in ceramic sockets) to 150 degrees F. or more. I bought a cheap controller and thermocouple from Amazon to regulate the temp for about $20 and it works great! Getting out of the candle business and into woodworking and plan to use the heat cabinet to kiln dry resawn firewood. I covered the inside of the box with metal HVAC tape to reflect the heat and reduce loss through the box itself. Give it a try!

Comment: See [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/how-to-heat-a-wood-kiln-to-140-f-safely#comment32381_14442) for a thought on buying mains voltage electrical components from Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a commercial heaters that has a shut off at 157 instead of 120 on Amazon.  If you use a temperature controller you should easily be able to get up to 140 if you set the heater on low and slowly work up to 140 to make sure the heater does not get over 157.

However take note most dehumidifiers won't work over 105, as dehumidifiers work by cooling the air down past the dew point.  Thus you will need to control humidity by pumping the air out of the chamber let it cool down and then use a dehumidifier.

Comment: Be _exceedingly_ cautious buying electrical parts on Amazon. They'll sell just about anything (especially through their affiliate store links) that someone can make. Many of the things sold there do not meet NRTL testing standards and do not have certification marks like UL, CSA, Kitemark, or ETL. Without these marks on your products, your insurance company could, potentially, deny a claim if something goes catastrophically wrong. That would be far more expensive than if you bought the product at a local, regulated, store...

Comment: @FreeMan - it's also not uncommon for stuff on Amazon to have FAKE UL, CSA, etc marks. Just don't is usually your best bet on that front.